# What's the equivalent of 'registering an ISR in DOS' in linux

Tags: linux, assembly

In DOS the isr(interrupt service routine) can be registered by the following code:

```
mov    ah,25H
mov    al,0BH
lea    dx,handler
mov    bx,seg handler
mov    ds,bx
int    21H
```

The procedure will handle the `0BH` interrupt.

I want to know : what's the  equivalent of this in linux?

Comment: Are you talking about user-space or kernel-space code?  If it's the former, then interrupts don't exist, you handle signals instead.

Comment: If working at user-level on the application side, read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ first, then the http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/

Answer (score 1):

In DOS, you can use the function `25h` to install a handler for both a system call or a hardware interrupt from a device. Real mode code usually doesn't care about hardware exceptions, but there are some of them that certain DOS programs use, such as "Coprocessor not present", used to emulate a 80x87 for CAD programs, and so on.

In Linux you can do these things, but only from kernel mode, i.e. a device driver.

- Exceptions : they are handled automatically by the kernel. Your (user) program receives a signal. Handle it. Your kernel program should not trigger any exception (except the page fault, which is recoverable)
- System calls : a driver can alter the system call table, adding or modifying the existent ones by writting to the `syscalls` array. More information [here](http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/CSI500/Fal11/Labs/L06/OwnSyscall.html)
- Hardware interrupts : use the `request_interrupt()` function to install a handler for a hardware interrupt tied to an `IRQ` (not the same as the interrupt number from DOS)

Answer (score 0):

More or less the equivalent of this is the kernel function:

request_irq(11, handler, ... )

See manual:
http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux-mandocs/2.4.24/request_irq.html